# Direction of rotation or handedness in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I've noticed that when I rotate my model around the Z axis, like this:

```
model.rotateZ(rotatedAngle * Math.PI / 180);
```

it seems to rotate counter-clockwise around the axis.

- Is this observation accurate?
- Is this documented somewhere? I couldn't find it, perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms.
- Is this configurable?
- Most importantly what is the best practice for managing rotations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Three.js uses the [right handed system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) and this means counter clockwise is default rotation. See [here](https://www.evl.uic.edu/ralph/508S98/coordinates.html) for all rotation rules...

[image: source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule]

*Left the left handed system (clockwise), right the right handed system (counter clockwise)*

So then adding something to your angle rotates counter clockwise
and removing something rotates clockwise.

```
function rotate(){
    mesh1.rotation.z += 0.01;  // rotates counter clockwise
    mesh2.rotation.z -= 0.01;  // rotates clockwise
}
```

[A Fiddle here to demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/mhxtdfp8/)

Comment: Thanks! I wish that was easier to find in the threes documentation.

Comment: Just as a point of clarification, the coordinate system shown in the answer's image is not THREE.js's coordinate system.  THREE.js is y+ = up, z- = forward, x+ = right.  This is pretty typical for right-handed coordinate systems.  The one shown in the image is z+ = up, y+ = forward, x+ = right.

Comment: I recommend using the AxesHelper if you want to double-check your coordinate system: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/AxesHelper